# libjpeg-turbo-dev Undefined reference and package issue

Tags: package-management, source-code

i am trying to do some coding using the lib but i cannot even compile a simple code, and when i asked about it in help section for the developers i got that the issue is from the package on the system which is ubuntu. i have ubuntu 13.10 64bit version and here is the simple code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <jpeglib.h>
int main(void){
  struct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;
  struct jpeg_error_mgr jerr;
  cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error(&jerr);
  jpeg_create_decompress(&cinfo);

  return 0;
}
```

and here is the error i got. this same code works well as reported to me
Undefined reference to jpeg_CreateDecompress() error when using libjpeg